# Is there a way to reuse code in Static classes since Inheritance is impossible?

Tags: c#, class, static, overriding, reusability

Sometimes I have static types which are really supposed to be static but in rare cases I need to reuse some of their code (couple of methods). I could create an interface or another basic abstract class and solve the problem for several static classes which all really require same methods and members to be overridden but **slightly modified**. But it still will require me to copy paste large sections of code and I will not be able mark them as static anymore.

Comment: If you need to reuse those static methods, can't you... you know... *call them?*

Comment: why static if u need inheritance?

Comment: you can hide the constructor, then the class object could not be created by developer.

Comment: Please give some sample code. I'm not really sure what you're asking, since any time you call a function (even a static function on a static class), you are in essence "reusing" that code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve this by building Singleton classes. They can then leverage a base `abstract` class as well as any necessary inheritance hierarchy, but they still could have static methods that just leverage the private instance if necessary.

Have a look at Jon Skeet's [blog on Singleton's](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) so that you build yours properly.

Comment: @DavidDiamond, are you clearly understanding that you are creating only **one instance** for the lifetime of the application?

Comment: @DavidDiamond, but remember, anything that didn't leverage the inheritance hierarchy would not need to leverage the `Instance` property when using reflection. Not everything in the class needs to be an instance member. That's why I suggested it. And in fact, you could mask all instance operations with a static member. Consider a static method that then internally just grabs the `Instance.InstanceMethodName`.

Comment: @DavidDiamond, and I have to ask, this concern you have with `Reflection` performing more poorly on instances than types, is it founded with some sort of benchmarks? I have built applications that have literally no static code - the entire application including the UX was interpreted - and we found no difference. `Reflection` still has to perform the lookup on the type. Setting a value in memory, whether it be static or instance, is the same operation.